# Moving a range of numbered files to specific folders

Tags: macos, osx-el-capitan, brackets

I'm on a Mac under OS X 10.11 and I have some file named "00000123.jpg" "00001234.jpg" "00002048.jpg" "00006543.jpg" etc.
There is also a CSV file formated with "FolderName;StartFileNumber;EndFileNumber" e.g. "Folder-05;00001486;00001507"

What works is displaying the read data as a dry run:

```
while IFS=";" read Folder StartNo EndNo ; do echo "$StartNo.jpg to $EndNo.jpg in $Folder/" ; done < <(cat ~/Test/FileSort.csv)
```

But when trying this for real it fails:

```
while IFS=";" read Folder StartNo EndNo ; do mkdir $Folder" ; mv {$StartNo..$EndNo}.jpg $Folder/ ; done < <(cat ~/Test/FileSort.csv)
```

Error is
mv: rename {00001937..00001982}.jpg to Folder-066/{00001937..00001982}.jpg: No such file or directory

The folders are generated correct and the files exist.
But it seams that the brace expansion did not work ?!?